Struggling to use future builder with multiple futures when loading init data with async call
I'm a bit stuck trying to implement futurebuilder in my main app (I have successfully used it elsewhere and I am struggling to get my head around what I am doing differently).
I have recreated the problem I have below from a bigger more complex app to try and pin down the bit I am stuck on... apologies if there is still some superfluous stuff in there but as I am not sure which bit is causing me the problem I left it in.
In summary I am loading some xml data which I need to display certain things from in the initial load.
If I load the data into tmp values and then set the state properties in setState it works but I have to set a lot of arbitrary values to the state properties which seems wrong.
This is the version of code that works (well it runs at least... the fact it is picking up the hard coded values in the real thing is less of an issue because I can set them to what I want and subsequent actions make everything correct).
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'load_xml.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final String xmlAssetPath = 'data.xml';

  DataTree dataTree = DataTree(categories: []);
  Category selectedCategory = Category(name: 'not_set', groupNames: []); 
  Group selectedGroup = Group(name: "not_set", items: []);
  String groupName ="Citrus";
  Item selectedItem = Item(name: "Orange");
  int selectedItemIndex = 0;

  void _loadData() async {
    DataTree tmpDataTree = await loadXml(xmlAssetPath);
    debugPrint ("Loading data tree...");
    for (var category in tmpDataTree.categories) {
      debugPrint ("Loading category ${category.name}...");
      if ((category.isDefault ?? false) && (category.defaultGroupName != null)) {
         debugPrint ("Setting groupName to ${category.defaultGroupName}...");
         groupName = category.defaultGroupName!;
       }
    } 
    debugPrint ("Loading selected group $groupName..."); 
    Group tmpSelectedGroup = await loadGroup(xmlAssetPath, groupName); 
    for (var item in tmpSelectedGroup.items) {
      debugPrint ("Loading item ${item.name}...");
      if (item.name == tmpSelectedGroup.defaultItemName) {
         selectedItem = item;
         selectedItemIndex = tmpSelectedGroup.items.indexOf(selectedItem);
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      dataTree = tmpDataTree;
      selectedGroup = tmpSelectedGroup;
    });
  }

  @override 
  void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    _loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: selectedCategory.name,
      home: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
          key: ValueKey(selectedGroup.items[index].name),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(selectedGroup.items[index].name),
            subtitle: Text((selectedGroup.items[index].name==selectedItem.name) ? "Selected" : "Not selected"),
          ),
        ),
        itemCount: selectedGroup.items.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

But ideally I want to avoid having the hard coded values so I tried to use FutureBuilder like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'load_xml.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final String xmlAssetPath = 'data.xml';

  Future<DataTree> dataTree;
  Category selectedCategory = Category(name: 'not_set', groupNames: []); 
  Future<Group> selectedGroup;
  // Group selectedGroup = Group(name: "not_set", items: []);
  String groupName ="Citrus";
  Item selectedItem = Item(name: "Orange");
  int selectedItemIndex = 0;

  void _loadData() async {
    dataTree = await loadXml(xmlAssetPath); 
    debugPrint ("Loading data tree...");
    for (var category in dataTree.categories) {
      debugPrint ("Loading category ${category.name}...");
      if ((category.isDefault ?? false) && (category.defaultGroupName != null)) {
         debugPrint ("Setting groupName to ${category.defaultGroupName}...");
         groupName = category.defaultGroupName!;
       }
    } 
    debugPrint ("Loading selected group $groupName..."); 
    selectedGroup = await loadGroup(xmlAssetPath, groupName); 
    for (var item in selectedGroup.items) {
      debugPrint ("Loading item ${item.name}...");
      if (item.name == selectedGroup.defaultItemName) {
         selectedItem = item;
         selectedItemIndex = selectedGroup.items.indexOf(selectedItem);
      }
    }
  }

  @override 
  void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    _loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder (
        future: Future.wait([dataTree,selectedGroup]),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return MaterialApp (
             title: snapshot.data![1].name,
             home: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                key: ValueKey(snapshot.data![1].items[index].name),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data![1].items[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text((snapshot.data![1].items[index].name==selectedItem.name) ? "Selected" : "Not selected"),
                ),
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data![1].items.length,
            )
           );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        }
    );
  }
}

But of course I get
lib/my_app_await_not_working.dart:23:16: Error: A value of type 'DataTree' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<DataTree>'.
 - 'DataTree' is from 'package:test_init/load_xml.dart' ('lib/load_xml.dart').
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
    dataTree = await loadXml(xmlAssetPath); 
...

which I figured out from here is because I am using await it stops it being a future.
However if I do this..
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'load_xml.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final String xmlAssetPath = 'data.xml';

  Future<DataTree> dataTree;
  Category selectedCategory = Category(name: 'not_set', groupNames: []); 
  Future<Group> selectedGroup;
  // Group selectedGroup = Group(name: "not_set", items: []);
  String groupName ="Citrus";
  Item selectedItem = Item(name: "Orange");
  int selectedItemIndex = 0;

  void _loadData() {
    dataTree = loadXml(xmlAssetPath); 
    debugPrint ("Loading data tree...");
    for (var category in dataTree.categories) {
      debugPrint ("Loading category ${category.name}...");
      if ((category.isDefault ?? false) && (category.defaultGroupName != null)) {
         debugPrint ("Setting groupName to ${category.defaultGroupName}...");
         groupName = category.defaultGroupName!;
       }
    } 
    debugPrint ("Loading selected group $groupName..."); 
    selectedGroup = loadGroup(xmlAssetPath, groupName); 
    for (var item in selectedGroup.items) {
      debugPrint ("Loading item ${item.name}...");
      if (item.name == selectedGroup.defaultItemName) {
         selectedItem = item;
         selectedItemIndex = selectedGroup.items.indexOf(selectedItem);
      }
    }
  }

  @override 
  void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    _loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder (
        future: Future.wait([dataTree,selectedGroup]),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return MaterialApp (
             title: snapshot.data![1].name,
             home: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                key: ValueKey(snapshot.data![1].items[index].name),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data![1].items[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text((snapshot.data![1].items[index].name==selectedItem.name) ? "Selected" : "Not selected"),
                ),
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data![1].items.length,
            )
           );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        }
    );
  }
}

I then get things like
ib/my_app_fb_not_working.dart:14:20: Error: Field 'dataTree' should be initialized because its type 'Future<DataTree>' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'DataTree' is from 'package:test_init/load_xml.dart' ('lib/load_xml.dart').
  Future<DataTree> dataTree;
                   ^^^^^^^^

In both cases I also get errors like.
lib/my_app_fb_not_working.dart:25:35: Error: The getter 'categories' isn't defined for the class 'Future<DataTree>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'DataTree' is from 'package:test_init/load_xml.dart' ('lib/load_xml.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'categories'.
    for (var category in dataTree.categories) {
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^

I've tried a bunch of different things to declare them but can't figure out how to get the data in via a future.
For ref if it helps to replicate here are the other modules i am testing with (don't worry too much about the inefficient/buggy xml loading I can sort that out later.. I think it works well enough from a pov of testing this)....
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_app.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

load_xml.dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';   
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';   
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
import 'dart:async';

class DataTree {
  List<Category> categories = [];
  DataTree({required this.categories}); 
}

class Category {
  final List<String> groupNames; 
  final String name;
  final bool? isDefault;
  final String? defaultGroupName;
  const Category({required this.groupNames, required this.name, this.isDefault, this.defaultGroupName}); 
}

class Group { 
  final List<Item> items;
  final String name;
  final bool? isDefault;
  final String? defaultItemName; 

  const Group({required this.items, required this.name, this.isDefault, this.defaultItemName});
}

class Item { 
  final String name;
  final bool? isDefault;
  const Item({required this.name, this.isDefault});
}

Future<Group> loadGroup(String xmlAssetPath, String groupName) async {

  debugPrint ("Inside load group for $groupName");

  Group group;
  List<Item> itemList = []; 

  String xmlString = await rootBundle.loadString(xmlAssetPath); 
  final document = xml.XmlDocument.parse(xmlString);

  final groups = document.findAllElements('group')              
       .where((group) => group.getAttribute('name') == groupName)
       .toList();

  // do we need these?
  String name='not set';

  bool isGroupDefault = false;
  bool isItemDefault = false;
  String defaultItemName='not set';

  for (var element in groups) {
    String? name = element.getAttribute('name');
    debugPrint("Checking group $name");

    if (name == groupName) { 
      debugPrint("Matches $name");
      name = element.getAttribute('name').toString();
      isGroupDefault = (element.getAttribute('default') == 'true') ? true : false;

      final items = element.findElements('item'); 
      for (var item in items) {
        String name = item.getAttribute('name').toString();
        debugPrint("Parsing item $name");
        isItemDefault = (item.getAttribute('default') == 'true') ? true : false;
          
        if (isItemDefault == true) {
            defaultItemName = name; 
            debugPrint ("Got default item $defaultItemName");     
        } // change this to id at some point

        itemList.add ( Item (
          name: name,
        ));

        isItemDefault = false;
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  group = Group (
      items: itemList,
      name: groupName,
      isDefault: isGroupDefault,
      defaultItemName: defaultItemName,
  );
  return group;
}

Future<DataTree> loadXml(String xmlAssetPath) async { 
  DataTree dataTree;
  List<Category> categoryList = []; 

  String xmlString = await rootBundle.loadString(xmlAssetPath); 

  final document = xml.XmlDocument.parse(xmlString);

  final categories = document.findAllElements('category'); 

  for (var element in categories) {
    List<String> groupNames = []; 
    String categoryName = element.getAttribute('name').toString();

    final groups = element.findElements('group');
    for (var element in groups) { 
      String groupName = element.getAttribute('name').toString();
      groupNames.add(groupName);

    } 
    categoryList.add(Category(
        name: categoryName,
        groupNames: groupNames,
    )); 
  } 
  dataTree = DataTree(categories: categoryList);
  return dataTree;
}

assets/data.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

<data>
  <category name="Fruit" default="true">
    <group name="Citrus">
      <item name="Orange"/>
      <item name="Lemon" default="true"/>
      <item name="Lime"/>
    </group>
    <group name="Berry" default="true">
      <item name="Strawberry"/>
      <item name="Raspberry" default="true"/>
      <item name="Gooseberry"/>
    </group>
    <group name="Exotic">
      <item name="Pineapple"/>
      <item name="Papaya"/>
      <item name="Mango"/>
    </group>
  </category>
  <category name="Vegetable">
    <group name="Root">
      <item name="Carrot"/>
      <item name="Potato"/>
      <item name="Parsnip"/>
    </group>
    <group name="Brassica">
      <item name="Cabbage"/>
      <item name="Broccoli"/>
      <item name="Kale"/>
    </group>
  </category>
</data>


rename void _loadData() async { to Future<(DataTree, Group)> _loadData() async { and return (dataTree, selectedGroup); from it, not you can use it in initState like myFuture = _loadData();

but if you used Future.wait then maybe you want to load your xml and selected group not sequentially? if so, you should create two async methods for that

This makes sense. Will take a look when I can get back to it later. Thanks

@pskink just trying to get my head around this... is that an example of a record being returned inside the future?

you mean how to use it with FutureBuilder?

Future<(DataTree, Group)> ... is the (DataTree, Group) a record? I hadn't seen this syntax before. Or is it something straightforward that I am just missing...

(Btw I got it working... just making sure I understand what is going on... should I post the working version as the answer and credit to you? What is the correct etiquette here?)

Ok @pskink i posted the working version thanks. Lmk if you want to repost it to get the points or someting

feel free to post a self answer then, and yes (DataTree, Group) is a record, nice thing when you are for example returning multiple values from a function (of course you could create a class for this, but a record is a very handy solution in cases like that)

got it. thanks for this I spent ages trying to figure this out and it still wasn't obvious

So thanks to @pskink I have a working version... using a record makes it quite neat although I don't think that is the thing that actually fixed it - rather using a separate future returned from _loadData and then adding a load of ? and ! to override nulls - but I just don't have time to do all the differential diagnosis to see exactly what fixed what (feel free to add comments to make my code more robust).
As an aside I like the fact that retrieving elements from records makes my code look a bit more like Perl :)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'load_xml.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final String xmlAssetPath = 'data.xml';
  
  Future<(DataTree, Group)>? initFuture;
  DataTree? dataTree;
  Category? selectedCategory; // = Category(name: 'not_set', groupNames: []); 
  Group? selectedGroup;
  // Group selectedGroup = Group(name: "not_set", items: []);
  String? groupName; // ="Citrus";
  Item? selectedItem; // = Item(name: "Orange");
  int selectedItemIndex = 0;

  Future<(DataTree, Group)> _loadData() async {
    dataTree = await loadXml(xmlAssetPath); 
    debugPrint ("Loading data tree...");
    for (var category in dataTree!.categories) {
      debugPrint ("Loading category ${category.name}...");
      if ((category.isDefault ?? false) && (category.defaultGroupName != null)) {
         debugPrint ("Setting groupName to ${category.defaultGroupName}...");
         groupName = category.defaultGroupName!;
       }
    } 
    debugPrint ("Loading selected group $groupName..."); 
    selectedGroup = await loadGroup(xmlAssetPath, groupName!); 
    for (var item in selectedGroup!.items) {
      debugPrint ("Loading item ${item.name}...");
      if (item.name == selectedGroup!.defaultItemName) {
         selectedItem = item;
         selectedItemIndex = selectedGroup!.items.indexOf(selectedItem!);
      }
    }
    return (dataTree!, selectedGroup!);
  }

  @override 
  void initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    initFuture = _loadData();
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<(DataTree, Group)> (
        future: initFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<(DataTree, Group)> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return MaterialApp (
             title: snapshot.data!.$2.name,
             home: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                key: ValueKey(snapshot.data!.$2.items[index].name),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data!.$2.items[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text((snapshot.data!.$2.items[index].name==selectedItem!.name) ? "Selected" : "Not selected"),
                ),
              ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.$2.items.length,
            )
           );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        }
    );
  }
}


btw instead of snapshot.data!.$2 you can use final (dataTree, group) = snapshot.data! before return MaterialApp(...

Ack. But also... line noise ftw :D

for more check multiple returns

ta. this is really useful.

So thinking about it... in the build I have to use the state variables as in the real thing they can change in future using setState ... so does it make sense to actually just use a single DataTree value in the initFuture and then just access all the state variables in the build method (kinda using initFuture as semaphore for initial load but not relying on it for the actual values as for that to have been return the other state variables must have been set). This seems to work but feels a bit brittle.

ALso going down this route I am wondering if there could be problem or inefficiency using FutureBuilder here as every time I do setState for the other values initially loaded in _loadData it is doing an unnecessary FutureBuilder check... is that something I should be concerned with?

why would you want to use FutureBuilder and setState together?

Using FutureBuilder because on start up it needs to wait for the initial state from the data load... but then in the real thing I subsequently change some of those states with methods in the main app but that are passed into the widget tree as callbacks.

So if you want to use multiple "states" then use StreamBuilder rather than FutureBuilder

Will look into this. Thanks. Interested to know what the inherent bad of using FutureBuilder and setState together is. Is it just inefficient or is it there be dragons kinda situaion.

The other approach I considered is doing the initial load in main and passing those values in to the app which can then be managed via setstate. Maybe this is the way

and cannot you pass those values to  MyApp so it has real data provided from outside?

Yes that's what I'm thinking. Although I might want to reload the data after launch so maybe it does make sense to keep in inside myapp. The futurebuilder/setstate mashup is working great though so I'm going to leave it until I get round to refactoring the whole thing properly. Thanks for all the help really appreciate it.

Time to stop using FutureBuilder and start using Riverpod.  Riverpod can nicely manage cached data from async operations, and aggregate those for overall results.  I stopped using FutureBuilder as soon as I became comfortable with Riverpod providers.

Ah yes this is certainly on my to-do list but was hoping I could get this working in the meantime!

I suspect you will be able to do that without Riverpod, but it will take as much fidgeting around as simply learning Riverpod for future projects. :)

So looking like Riverpod could be a good way forward... still its useful to understand exactly why other approaches are difficult to then really understand why Riverpod works the way it does.

Because FutureBuilder has state buried inherent in the control flow.  This kind of state is harder to manage and in particular, harder to compose.  Riverpod providers are trivial to compose to get combined states.
